# Search using same query across structurally equal collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have multiple collections (one per customer) which are structurally equivalent and are named to encode the customer name. For example, to keep things simple, say these collections have a single field, `hostIp`:

```
{
   "hostIp": "10.0.75.1"
}
```

For two collections such as the ones below, I would like to query for all records where the hostIp has a certain value. Can this be done in a single query or are separate queries required?

```
my.collection.abc
my.collection.def
```

Comment: Unless there is some relationship between two collections you may have to do with two queries. What is the purpose of such a query? There is a `$unionWith` aggregation stage which may be useful.

Comment: There is no relationship between the collections. This query would be in support of an operational API (non-customer-specific) where nodes need to be brought down cleanly. I'll take a look at `$unionWith` - thanks.